# How do I add right-justified Facebook and Twitter buttons to the footer of my website?

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, footer

I am using Volusion for my e-commerce website, and would like to add Facebook and Twitter buttons/icons to the footer of my website (sort of like the "cc-wiki" and "Peak Internet" logos in the footer of this page).

Here is the current HTML code for my footer.  What code do I add to leave the Copyright and "Powered by Volusion" text left-justified, and add the desired buttons on the same line, but right-justified?

```
<div id="footer_bottom">
    <!--<div id="footer_right" class="right">-->

    <!--</div>-->
    <div id="copyright">
        <a href="/terms.asp">Copyright &copy; <script type="text/javascript">document.write((new Date()).getFullYear());</script>  &nbsp;Config_CompanyNameLegal&nbsp; All Rights Reserved.</a>

        <!-- ==========================================================================================
            VOLUSION LINK - BEGIN
        ===============================================================================================
        Customer has agreed per Volusion’s Terms of Service (http://www.volusion.com/agreement_monthtomonth.asp) to maintain a text hyperlink to "http://www.volusion.com" in the footer of the website. The link must be standard html, contain no javascript, and be approved by Volusion. Removing this link breaches the Volusion agreement.-->   

        <br><a style="color: #F0F0F0" href="http://www.volusion.com" title="Shopping Cart Software" target="_blank">Powered by Volusion</a>
    </div>
    <!-- ==========================================================================================
        VOLUSION LINK - END
    =========================================================================================== -->    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `float: left` or `float:right` on your divs (something of this effect, it's **untested** just play with CSS).

```
<div id="footer_bottom" style="display: block; width: 100%">
    <div id="powered" style="float: left">Powered by Volusion</div>

    <!--</div>-->
    <div id="copyright" style="float:right" ><a href="/terms.asp">Copyright &copy; <script type="text/javascript">document.write((new Date()).getFullYear());</script>  &nbsp;Config_CompanyNameLegal&nbsp; All Rights Reserved.</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Bear in mind that you should have a CSS (stylesheet) and put everything that I put inside `style=""` into CSS.

e.g.

```
/* CSS */
#powered {
   float: left;
}
```